# Crossrider - Cannot get pixel data from image using Canvas

Tags: canvas, crossrider

I am using crossrider to make a plugin that extract images with specific pixels. I use canvas to get the pixel images. but what i am seeing now is that when i do `var data = context.getImageData(m, n, 1,1).data` where `m` and `n` are the pixel locations, the code breaks from there. as in nothing happens. I added a console.log statement before and after this line but the statement after it never prints, which means its not able to get the data. does that mean image cannot read the pixel? i have uploaded the image to pinterest which compresses the image and hence the size and pixel colors get affected. any help would be appreciated here.

Comment: Could you show us more of the relevant code in your post? The syntax is correct and if there where CORS issues you should at least have gotten a black transparent pixel back ([0,0,0,0]).. I suspect (as of now) that the canvas size could be invalid but lets see some more code how you setup the canvas and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

@ueg1990 I would tend to think you are experiencing CORS or canvas size issues, but like @ken mentioned some more code would be in order.

Nevertheless, I created an extension using the following HTML and *extension.js* code based on the [W3Schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/canvas_getimagedata.asp) and it worked without issue. Notice, that the image is in the same domain as he canvas and that I resize the canvas to match the image size.

**HTML**:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="myImage" src="canvas.jpg">
  <canvas id="myCanvas">Canvas not supported by your browser</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

**extension.js**:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var img=document.getElementById("myImage");
c.height = img.height;
c.width = img.width;
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
var imgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,c.width,c.height);
// invert colors
for (var i=0;i<imgData.data.length;i+=4)
  {
  imgData.data[i]=255-imgData.data[i];
  imgData.data[i+1]=255-imgData.data[i+1];
  imgData.data[i+2]=255-imgData.data[i+2];
  imgData.data[i+3]=255;
  }
ctx.putImageData(imgData,0,0);
```

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: hello shlomo, thank you for replying. i would really like the help of a Crossrider employee for this. i did exactly as u did and it works for images in imgur.com but nothing happens in instagram's website. the function just returns when it gets to the line var data = context.getImageData(m, n, 1,1).data. I have tested this in Firefox and nothing prints in the console when i try to print it. i will add my code below so u have an idea of what i am trying to do. ur help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic code that i am trying to execute. it works perfectly in imgur.com but not in instagram. The following code is at extension.js:

```
appAPI.message.addListener(function(msg) {
    console.log("Inside listener!!!");
    if (msg.action === 'findImage') {
        console.log(document.location.href);
        test();
    }
});

var RATIO = 0.06;
var length; 
function test() {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
         if( divs[i].getAttribute("src") != "" && divs[i].getAttribute("src") != null && divs[i].getAttribute("src") != undefined  ){
             var src = divs[i].getAttribute("src");
             console.log(src);
             divs[i].getAttribute("height"));
             var img = new Image();

            img.onload = function() {
                //alert("loading photo");

                //console.log(this.width + " " + this.height);
                var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.height = this.height;
                canvas.width = this.width;
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                context.drawImage(this, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
                heightOfImage = this.height;
                widthOfImage = this.width;
                length = Math.floor(RATIO * canvas.width);
    console.log("Before");
            var data = context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height).data;           
    console.log(data);
            console.log("Pass");

/*
                for(var m = 0; m < this.width; m++ ) {
                    for(var n = 0; n < this.height; n++) {
                        console.log("Getting data!!!");
                        console.log(context.getImageData(m, n, 1,1).data);
                        var data = context.getImageData(m, n, 1,1).data;
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                }
*/                  


            };

            img.src = src;
        img.crossOrigin = '';
            //console.log(img.src);

         }
     }
}

});
```

From the code, i can see "Before" print but no data printing and no "Pass" print

Comment: Thanks ... there is an syntax error, an extra bracket ")", in the following code: divs[i].getAttribute("height")); Additionally, this appears to be partial code as there is an extra "});" at the end. Any chance you can explain why you are checking div tags for a "src" attribute (usually found on img tags) and provide the full code or extension id?